# Object does not return to original position when released cs4

Tags: drag-and-drop, position, sprite, actionscript-2, flash-cs4

I am making a drag and drop activity where multiple items are to be placed at the same target. I have action code on the main time line and then code attached to a sprite.

**Problems:**

1. When I release the object if it is correct it should snap to the top of that section. If it is incorrect it should return to its original orientation to be picked up again. Unfortunately it stays where I placed it, and does not move back to original place when it is incorrect. I have fixed other issues with this flash file as to if code is supposed to be on the main time line or in the sprite, but this does not seem to have an effect after the object is released.  Near the end of the script there is `_root.rlamp1.gotoAndPlay(1)` this is a buzzer that goes off if the answer is incorrect. This is working correctly.
2. I do not know if these are related Items but if the correct placement is given I want the next item to start in the original position, but it is starting where my mouse is instead of the original position.  I am relatively new to coding and am trying to make an activity for my science class to get instant feedback to see if they understand to concept.

Thanks for your help.

```
  // [Action in Frame 1]

 answername = Array();
 answerdest = Array();
 answername[0] = "gravel";
 answerdest[0] = "1";
 answername[1] = "nuts and bolts";
 answerdest[1] = "1";
 answername[2] = "oxygen";
 answerdest[2] = "2";
 answername[3] = "helium";
 answerdest[3] = "2";
 answername[4] = "gold";
 answerdest[4] = "2";


        dbCount = 0;

        dbutton.duplicateMovieClip("dbutton" + dbCount,dbCount * 100);

        dbutton.visible = false;

        dbutton0.answer = answerdest[dbCount];

        dbutton0.theText.text = answername[dbCount];



    // This code is on the sprite and not on the main actionscript

   onClipEvent (load)
    {
        this.defx = _x;
        this.defy = _y;
        if (this.theText.text.length > 20)
        {
            this.theText._height = 31;
            this.theBox._height = 27;
        }
        else
        {

            this.theText._height = 19;
            this.theBox._height = 19;
        } // end else if
    }
    on (press)
    {
        if (this.noDrag !=true)
        {
            startDrag (this,false);
        }
    }


    on (release)
    {
        if (this.noDrag != true)
        {
            stopDrag ();
            if(this.hitTest(_root["dz" + this.answer]))
            {
                totalHeight = 0;
                for (v = 0; v < _root.dbCount; v++)
                {
                    if (_root["dbutton" + v].answer == this.answer)
                    {
                        totalHeight = totalHeight + _root["button" + v].theBox._height ;
                    } // end if
                } // end of for
                ++_root.dbCount;
                this .duplicateMovieClip("dbutton" + _root.dbCount, _root.dbCount * 100);
                _root["dbutton" + _root.dbCount]._x = this.defX;
                _root["dbutton" + _root.dbCount]._y = this.defY;
                _root["dbutton" + _root.dbCount].answer = _root.answerdest[_root.dbCount + 1];
                _root["dbutton" + _root.dbCount].theText.text = _root.answername[_root.dbCount +1];
                if (_root["dbutton" + _root.dbCount].theText.text == "undefined")
                {
                    _root["dbutton" + _root.dbCount].theText.text = "Finished!";
                    _root["dbutton" + _root.dbCount].noDrag = true;
                } // end if
                this.noDrag = true;
                this._y = _root["dz" + this.answer]._y + totalHeight;
                this._x = _root["dz" + this.answer]._x - _root["dz" + this.answer]._width / 2;
                ++_root["dz" + this.answer].numItems;
                _root.glamp1.gotoAndPlay (1);

            }
            else
            {
                this.X = this.defX;
                this._Y = this.defY;
                _root.rlamp1.gotoAndPlay(1);
            } // end if
        } // end else if
    }
```

Comment: is it really actionscript 3?

Comment: The code that specifically looks fishy is `onClipEvent (load)` and `on (press)` and `on (release)`. That is not AS3 syntax. Where did you get that from? Don't those lines throw crazy errors?! It look like something I remember from AS2. Since it isn't throwing an error, I'm guessing you aren't using a debugger version of flash. Try running your code with ctrl+Shift+enter to run in debug mode and let me know what errors it throws.

Comment: I have run it using ctrl+shift+enter and no errors occur.  The code was obtained by decompiling a swf file that does what I want it do do, once I figure out the code I want to change the items so that it suits my purposes.

Comment: I have taken peoples advice and started from scratch so I will post my progress in a new thread.  Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are misspelled variable names and properties in the sprite code.

Replace these lines

```
this.X = this.defX;
this._Y = this.defY;
```

with those lines

```
this._x = this.defx;
this._y = this.defy;
```

and your code should work.